# Update using Sum -Error

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Keep on getting error

> you tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression

My SQL looks as follows:

```
UPDATE TblField LEFT JOIN TblTempStats ON TblField.DomainCatID = TblTempStats.DomainCatID 
SET TblTempStats.EmptyFields = Sum(IIf([fieldname] Is Null,1,0));
```

Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Missing a From TblField?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a domain aggregate for this in my opinion, it avoids the error:

```
UPDATE TblTempStats 
SET TblTempStats.EmptyFields = 
    DSum(
       "IIf([fieldname] Is Null,1,0)", 
       "TblField",
       IIf(
          TblTempStats.DomainCatID Is Null,
          "TblField.DomainCatID Is Null",
          "TblField.DomainCatID = " & TblTempStats.DomainCatID
       )
    )
```

Comment: Hi, get error that I need to use an updateable Query - any other ideas? Thank you

Comment: Works for all values - except if DomainCatID is null, which I can live with, but do you think there is a way to include null domain cat iD - it is present in the tbltempstats (domaincatid null is a value)